# Selecting whole row in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to select whole row of DataGridView, when I click on some cell in it.

I added this code in  CellMouseDown event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{   
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

And it doesnt work, when I add this line to CellMouseClick event, it works, but it is slowly, it wait for mouse release, and then select it.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

There are property in GridView  Related Of Mode Of Selecting Row in gridview

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

You Can Reference To This Document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you select the option **Full Row Select** into the properties of the Datagrid like this:

[image: Full row select]